# Get values by key pattern in StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to use a pattern to retrieve all keys matching a pattern by `Stackexchange.Redis`.

**Code**

```
KEYS *o*
```

Comment: Are you aware that you shouldn't (in general) use the KEYS statement in live setups? Reason: O(n). See the docs, that's why SCAN is implemented.

Comment: @TwBert thanks.. Redis in Sort statement use SCAN?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the project homepage is linked [Where are `KEYS`, `SCAN`, `FLUSHDB` etc?](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan) which gives full details on how to access this, and why it isn't on `IDatabase`. I should point out that you should avoid `KEYS` on a production server. The library will automatically try to use `SCAN` instead if it is available - which is less harmful but should still be treated with some caution. It would be preferable to explicitly store related keys in a set or hash.

Comment: @MarkGravell, would you please clarify why the server.Keys(pattern: "*foo*") shouldn't be used if we are using 2.8+ instance of Redis? I read the link/page you refer to but it seems to contradict the advice given at https://redis.io/commands/scan where it says:

 "Since these commands allow for incremental iteration, returning only a small number of elements per call, they can be used in production without the downside of commands like KEYS".

Comment: @Jeff I said it should still be "treated with some caution" - not that it shouldn't be used. Frankly, redis is just *slow* for this scenario (on a busy server) - it is O(N) for N=number of keys on server. I would advocate using a *set* that contains the active keys for your scenario, so you can use SMEMBERS / SSCAN

Comment: @MarkGravel - Thank you.

Comment: @MarcGravell If you do that, how do you deal with items that expire? If I store an item with a TTL of N minutes, after that time the key name will still be in my list but my saved item will be gone and my list of keys will be stale.

Comment: @howcheng indeed; if you go with key sets, your code would need to deal with missing records appropriately; you could also use the `SORT` instruction, which allows the `GET` modifier to be used to perform a "gather" operation (essentially doing an "inner join", in SQL terms)