# Get all keys in Redis cluster

Tags: redis, command-line-interface, redis-cluster

I am using Redis cluster version `redis-5.0.5`. I want to see all the keys present in my Redis cluster. I know for standalone we use `KEYS *` to get all the keys.

what is the way to see all keys in Redis cluster?

```
$ redis-cli -h hostname -p 90001 -c 
hostname:90001> KEYS *
(empty list or set)

// I have data on my cluster
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Basically, you'd need to run `KEYS *` (not in production, please!) on every one of the nodes. The cli can do this with the '--cluster call' command, like so:

```
redis-cli --cluster call hostname:90001 KEYS "*"
```

Comment: I have 10 hosts. are there some commands coming in next release?

Comment: You need to call this only once - the `--cluster call` executes the specified command on each of the nodes in the cluster.

Comment: `call` argus seems great. but not works on windows `redis-cli.exe 3.2.100`.

Comment: @ItamarHaber this works fine for me. however, I noticed, this is returning `2*no_of_keys`  as this query is including both master and slave.

Comment: @roottraveller thanks for bumping this, I was actually aware of this shortcoming and you reminded me about the relevant pull request that addresses it (https://github.com/redis/redis/pull/6491) so you can expect it to be available in the next versions.

Comment: How to use `--cluster call` option in RedisInsight-v2?

Comment: `redis-cli --cluster help` said you can use `--cluster-only-masters` for `call` which likely mean only target master node.

Answer (score 1):

Requirement:

1. redis-cli
2. awk
3. grep
4. xargs

May be can try this assuming redis server reside in `localhost` with the default port `6379`:

```
redis-cli cluster nodes | awk '{print $2" "$3}' | grep master | awk -F @ '{print $1}' | awk -F : '{print " -h "$1" -p "$2" --scan"}' | xargs -L 1 redis-cli -c
```

Longer version base question above (`90001` port number seriously?) and also you can change the pattern (`*` no filter) for filtering certain key pattern:

```
redis-cli -h hostname -p 90001 cluster nodes | awk '{print $2" "$3}' | grep master | awk -F @ '{print $1}' | awk -F : '{print " -h "$1" -p "$2" --scan --pattern *"}' | xargs -L 1 redis-cli -c
```

It connects to any one of the redis node to get cluster info and then execute the keys scanning command on each of the master node.

Comment: The complex pipeline is rather ghastly; perhaps see [useless `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) though refactoring it properly will probably require access to the output from `redis-cli cluster nodes` so we can see what parts exactly you are picking out from there.

Answer (score 0):

The `SCAN` command may be what you're looking for, but it's O(N) so the more keys you have, the slower it's going to be. Also, check out this answer by Marc Gravell for another approach using sets: [Get values by key pattern in StackExchange.Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342514/get-values-by-key-pattern-in-stackexchange-redis/25344261#comment95253164_25344261)

Comment: Is there a database where adding more data is not going to be at least O(N) on a query like this?

Comment: SCAN also suffers the same issue of the KEYS. It will only return the keys from the scanned node hit by your load balancer so not an option

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to scan for all keys across nodes in your Redis cluster:

```bash
redis-cli -h localhost CLUSTER NODES \
  | grep master \
  | awk '{print $2}' \
  | cut -f1 -d '@' \
  | xargs -I '{}' redis-cli -u redis://{} --scan --pattern '*'
```

**TL;DR:** Get all the IP and port of all nodes in the cluster and scan for keys on each of them.

1. `redis-cli -h localhost CLUSTER NODES` obtains all information from the cluster configuration, including the node addresses to connect to for running commands
2. `grep master` selects only the master nodes
3. `awk '{print $2}'` selects the second column containg IP, port and cluster bus port
4. `cut -f1 -d '@'` to truncate the cluster bus port
5. `xargs` in combination with `redis-cli` to run the desired command. The `-u` flag makes it possible to provide server address and port in one string

Similarily you can also execute node-specific commands on every cluster nodes, see [here](https://konradreiche.com/blog/executing-redis-cluster-commands).

---

Also, in the above command, make sure to replace `localhost` with your actual host address, provide a port with `-p` if necessary.
Keep in mind, while the cost of scanning keys is less than `KEYS *`, it can still impact performance.

Answer (score 0):

Some times you want to get the keys those match a pattern and output as an unique list and can be passed to a command like `DEL` to delete them. You may use the following command:

```bash
redis-cli --cluster call REDIS_CLUSTER_ENDPOINT keys "pattern*"| grep -v "Calling keys" | cut -d ":" -f3 | grep "\S" | sort -u
```

**How it works**

```
redis-cli --cluster call REDIS_CLUSTER_ENDPOINT keys "pattern*": the command to scan keys with pattern "pattern*" in all nodes.
      grep -v "Calling keys"                                   : remove debug line that starts with Calling keys.
                cut -d ":" -f3                                 : print the third column which are the keys
                      grep "\S"                                : remove empty line
                            sort -u                            : output an unique list (since a same key can be found in multiple nodes)
```

DISCLAIMER: I did not test it in production with millions keys so please be aware when using it.

[image]