# Redis cli - KEYS * not showing all keys

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-cli

I am connecting to an AWS redis cluster using following command

```
redis-cli -c -h host.amazonaws.com -p 6379
```

I pushed two key "X1" and "X2" into redis cache from a springboot application (API methods are **not** annotated with `@Cacheable`) and now *when I run `KEYS *` from cli terminal it would list either "X1" or "X2" but not both*. GET for both keys works fine though.

`info keyspace` return following;

Keyspace

```
db0:keys=11,expires=1,avg_ttl=1975400
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have [cluster mode enabled](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/work-with-cluster-mode-on-amazon-elasticache-for-redis/). In cluster mode, the data you store is partitioned by key. One of the advantages of this is that you can now have a larger dataset than would reasonably fit on one machine (hundreds of terabytes, if you want) since every shard has some fraction of the entire data set.

A downside is that multi-key commands no long work like you would expect if the keys end up in different hash slots. The `KEYS` command is such a multi-key command.

To make a long story short:

- `KEYS` is apparently giving you only the keys on the cluster node you're hitting. It would perhaps have been nicer to give you an error, instead, but it doesn't.
- `GET` is unaffected: redis-cli, with the `-c` flag, knows how to find the right cluster node (perhaps after hitting the wrong one and being told the key has `MOVED`).

If you ask every individual primary node in your cluster for `KEYS *`, and add up all the results, you should get all the keys. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57692407/182402) has some examples of using the redis-cli to do this.