# How can retrieve values from a RedisResult if the result is a MultiBulk

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I can retrieve all keys in a Redis database by executing a command like:

```
RedisResult allRedisKeys = redisDatabase.Execute("KEYS", new List<object>
{
   "*"
})
```

But I can not make use of the variable allRedisKeys since its _value field is private. How can I extract the value from a RedisResult? In my case, _value holds a RedisResult[] and allRedisKeys has a RedisType of RedisType.MultiBulk.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, per [the documentation](https://redis.io/commands/keys), don't use the `KEYS` command in a production environment. However, you can use the [.Keys](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan.html) method per server, but this requires querying each server individually (and it's O(N) so also not the best).

For a faster (but more complex) solution, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342514/get-values-by-key-pattern-in-stackexchange-redis/25344261#25344261) by Marc Gravell. Basically, you store all your keys in a SET so you have O(1) response time.

This is my implementation of his suggestion:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class that keeps track of cache keys and the expiration of said keys. 
/// Uses a LIST to store the keys because it's faster than using SCAN on the entire Redis database.
/// Expirations are stored as ticks.
/// </summary>
public static class KeyAndExpirationTracker
{
    private const string ALL_KEYS = "ALL_KEYS";
    private const string EXPIRATION_SUFFIX = "|EXPIRATION";

    public static void StoreKeyAndExpiration(IDatabase db, string key, TimeSpan? timeToLive, ITransaction transaction)
    {
        string expiryKey = $"{key}{EXPIRATION_SUFFIX}";
        // although Redis will automatically replace an existing key, 
        // we still have to remove this in case this we went from having an expiration to not expiring
        db.KeyDelete(expiryKey);

        // add the item key to the list of keys
        transaction.SetAddAsync(key);
        // add the separate cache item for expiration (if necessary)
        if (timeToLive.HasValue)
        {
            DateTime expiry;
            try
            {
                expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(timeToLive.Value);
                transaction.StringSetAsync(expiryKey, expiry.Ticks.ToString());
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                // no expiration then
            }
        }
    }

    public static void StoreKeyAndExpiration(IDatabase db, string key, DateTime? expiration, ITransaction transaction)
    {
        string expiryKey = $"{key}{EXPIRATION_SUFFIX}";
        // although Redis will automatically replace an existing key, we still have to remove this in case this we went from having an expiration to not expiring
        db.KeyDelete(expiryKey);

        // add the item key to the list of keys for this client type
        transaction.SetAddAsync(cacheKey, key);
        // add the separate cache item for expiration (if necessary)
        if (expiration.HasValue)
        {
            transaction.StringSetAsync(expiryKey, expiration.Value.Ticks.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetKeys(IDatabase db)
    {
        RedisValue[] keys = db.SetMembers(ALL_KEYS));
        if (keys.Length == 0)
            return new string[0];

        List<string> expiredKeys = new List<string>(keys.Count());
        List<string> ret = new List<string>(keys.Count());

        // get expiration values using SORT with GET: https://redis.io/commands/sort
        RedisValue[] results = db.Sort(
            ALL_KEYS, 
            sortType: SortType.Alphabetic, 
            by: "notarealkey", // a (hopefully) non-existent key which causes the list to actually not be sorted
            get: new RedisValue[] { $"*{EXPIRATION_SUFFIX}", "#" } // # = "get the list item itself" which means the key in our case
        ));

        // SORT results will be in the same order as the GET parameters: 
        // result[0] = expiration (= null if no matching expiration item found)
        // result[1] = key
        // (repeat)
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string key = results[i + 1].Replace(EXPIRATION_SUFFIX, string.Empty);

            RedisValue expiryRedis = results[i];
            long ticks;
            if (long.TryParse(expiryRedis, out ticks))
            {
                DateTime expiry = new DateTime(ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                if (expiry <= DateTime.UtcNow)
                    expiredKeys.Add(key); // expired: add to list for removal
                else
                    ret.Add(key);
            }
            else
                ret.Add(key);
        }

        // remove any expired keys from list
        if (expiredKeys.Count > 0)
        {
            IBatch batch = db.CreateBatch();
            batch.SetRemoveAsync(cacheKey, expiredKeys.ConvertAll(x => (RedisValue)x).ToArray());
            foreach (string expiredKey in expiredKeys)
            {
                batch.KeyDeleteAsync(expiredKey);
            }
            batch.Execute();
        }

        return ret;
   }

    public static void RemoveKeyAndExpiration(IDatabase db, string key, ITransaction transaction)
    {
        // remove the key from the list and its corresponding expiration value
        string expiryKey = $"{key}{EXPIRATION_SUFFIX}";
        transaction.SetRemoveAsync(ALL_KEYS, key);
        transaction.KeyDeleteAsync(expiryKey);
    }

}
```

NOTE: The `StoreKeyAndExpiration` and `RemoveKeyAndExpiration` methods both take an `ITransaction` because I'm doing these operations in conjunction with adding or removing items to cache, so I want to wrap them all up into a single transaction. The transaction doesn't get executed here in case the calling method wants to add more operations to it.